# React : how to prevent escaping in data-attribute

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a JSON that looks like this { "id":"xyz", "height":1024, "width":1024 } which I would like to have in a data attribute like :

```
<div data-command='{"id":"xyz","height":1024,"width":1024}'></div>
```

but when I use react it escapes the string as shown below :

```
<div data-command='{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:1024,&quot;width&quot;:1024}'></div>
```

I use this code to generate the element

```
    React.createElement("div",
{ "data-command" : JSON.stringify({ "id":"xyz", "height":1024, "width":1024 }), null)
```

does anyone know how I can get the JSON without the " escaping?

If it's not possible how can I transform it back in javascript so I can use JSON.parse after?

Comment: Can't you just put `{ "id":"xyz", "height":1024, "width":1024 }` in the app state and use an index or other reference as the data-command? Or use id="xyz"?

Comment: hello, it's in gutemberg wordpress blocks so react is used on the admin part, but when it's rendered for the client react is not used any more and only the attribute is left (on the admin part I use the state indeed and have no issue thanks to that)

Comment: Does it have to be stringified as valid JSON? Else you could try using something like: `{ "data-command" : "{id:'xyz',height:1024,width:1024}" ), null)`.

Comment: yes it does, it needs to parse back by JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

The 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' attribute is precisely used for scenarios like this.

```
createMarkup() {
    return {__html: `<div data-command='{"id":"xyz","height":1024,"width":1024}'></div>`};
}

render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: this works, however I cannot introduce an extra parent, I guess it cannot be done has it's sets the InnerHtml

Comment: Please note that this is **insecure** and it can lead to XSS attacks! I'd suggest steering clear of `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. There is usually another solution that doesn't involve unsafe operations.